# location is wrong on the map in iOS

Tags: java, ios, google-maps, codenameone, locationmanager

I try to realize a small app in codename one for iOS. I show a Google map in a dialoge. I want to show my actual and real location on the embedded map.  I m shown on the map near 0N 0E - somewhere in the ocean. Here s the code I m using:

```
private void putMeOnMap(MapComponent map) {
    Location loc;
    try {
        loc = LocationManager.getLocationManager().getCurrentLocation();
        lastLocation = new Coord(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
        Image i = Image.createImage(10, 10, 0xff00ff00); //("/red_pin.png");
        PointsLayer pl = new PointsLayer();
        pl.setPointIcon(i);
        PointLayer p = new PointLayer(lastLocation, "aktueller Standort", i);
        p.setDisplayName(true);
        pl.addPoint(p);
        pl.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                PointLayer p = (PointLayer) evt.getSource();
                System.out.println("pressed " + p);

                Dialog.show("Details", "Du bist hier" + "\n" + p.getLatitude() + "|" + p.getLongitude(), "Ok", null);
            }
        });
        map.addLayer(pl);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly ask and accept Location tracking when utilizing it in an iOS app.

It will look something like this:

```
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.locationServicesEnabled
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    ...

    var shouldIAllow = false

    switch status {
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.Restricted:
        locationStatus = "Restricted Access to location"
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied:
        locationStatus = "User denied access to location"
    case CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined:
        locationStatus = "Status not determined"
    default:
        locationStatus = "Allowed to location Access"
        shouldIAllow = true
    }

    if (shouldIAllow == true) {
        NSLog("Location to Allowed")
        // Start location services
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    } else {
        NSLog("Denied access: \(locationStatus)")
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but I m using Java code not swift: I use codename one and develop in Java for iOS..

Comment: Sure, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [native mapping](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/) which looks much better on the device and also highlights your location as an option.

You should also use `getCurrentLocationSync()` rather than `getCurrentLocation()`. Notice that you must define the build hint `ios.locationUsageDescription` as explained [here](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).